# Unable to use $push and $each correctly in pymongo query

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm having an issue with my function it says it updated the document correctly but when looking in the database it did nothing

I'm able to $unset the key value pair but unable to push a new array to the element. I've tried summarySplit in as a list, string. Nothing works

```
def setValue(obj, values):
    db.SiteLog.update_one(obj,values)

setValue(
        {'_id':ObjectId(request.POST['id'])},
        {'$push': {'executiveSummary': {'$each':[summarySplit]}}}
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i checked your code, with nosql booster & pymongo driver.
it works totally fine. Check `request.POST['id']` , your database connection, and check if SiteLog is found & modified.
`WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })` .
Use breakpoint to evalute `db.SiteLog.update_one(obj,values)` multiple times and check the result.

Comment: I just checked my code again...it was suppose to be siteLog not SiteLog. Looks like I've been creating a new collection all this time while not updating the correct collection document. Thanks!